# Changing the color of a label without js if input validation fails

Tags: html, css, validation

I have a form, with a label and input type=text. I am using the pattern="" to validate the text and am displaying a message under the text input when the validation fails. I want to be able to change the color of the label as well as the text inside the text input, but cant seem to get it going. This is what I have so far. I do not want to use js.

```
               <div class="form-group address">
                <label for="address" class="form-group__names" id="invalid">Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" pattern="^\d+\s[A-z]+\s[A-z]+,\s+[A-z]+,\s+[A-z] 
                {2}\s+\d{5}" />
                <b></b>
              </div>

            .form-group input:invalid + b:before {
             content: "Form is invalid";
             color: red;
            }

             input[type="text"]:invalid + label#invalid {
             color: red;
            }
```

Comment: Try `input[type="text"]:invalid ~ label`, but it will select no previous siblings... maybe change the order of elements?

Comment: That works if the Address element follows the input field, but I need the Address label on top,

Comment: You can do it via css only if you reorder items [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/2hu6qz0f/2/) or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has [general sibling combinator ~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) and [adjacent sibling combinator +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)  and non of them can select previous sibling element. Therefor you gotta change the order of your elements, so the input comes first. This is one way to do it:

```css
.form-group input:invalid+b:before {
  content: "Form is invalid";
  color: red;
}

input[type="text"]:invalid~label {
  color: red;
}

.address {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.address label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group address">
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" pattern="^\d+\s[A-z]+\s[A-z]+,\s+[A-z]+,\s+[A-z]{2}\s+\d{5}" />
    <b></b>
    <label for="address" class="form-group__names" id="invalid">Address</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hu6qz0f/2/)

Comment: How to implement it if the label above input?

Comment: There is no wide browser support to somewhat *previous sibling selector*, I suggest you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector).